# Is it better to cache some value in a database table, or to recompute it each time?

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

For example, I have a table of bank users (user id, user name), and a table for transactions (user id, account id, amount).
Accounts have the same properties across different users, but hold different amounts (like Alex -> Grocery, it is specific to Alex, but all other users also have Grocery account).

The question is, would it be better to create a separate table of accounts (account id, user id, amount left) or to get this value by selecting all transactions with the needed user id and account id and just summing the 'amount' values? It seems that the first approach would be faster, but more prone to error and database corruption - I would need to update accounts every time the transaction happens. The second approach seems to be cleaner, but would it lead to significant speed reduction?

What would you recommend?

Comment: Optimisation is good.  Premature Optimisation (before you've encountered a *need*) can tie your hands in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

good question!

In my opinion you should always avoid duplicated data so I would go with the "summing" every time option

"It seems that the first approach would be faster, but more prone to error and database corruption - I would need to update accounts every time the transaction happens"

said everything, you are subject to errors and you'll have to build a mechanism to maintain the data up-to-date.

Dont forget that the first approach would be faster to select only. inserts updates and deletes would be slower because you will have to update your second table.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of [Denormalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormalization).

In general, denormalization is discouraged, but there are certain exceptions - bank account balances are typically one such exception.

So if this is your *exact* situation, I would suggest going with the separate table of accounts solution - but if you have far fewer records than a bank would typically, then I recommend the derived approach, instead.

Answer (score 2):

To some extent, it depends.

With "small" data volumes, performance will more than likely be OK.
But as data volumes grow, having to SUM all transactions may become costlier to the point at which you start noticing a performance problem.

Also to consider is data access/usage patterns. In a ready-heavy system, where you "write once, ready many", then the SUM approach hits performance on every read - in this scenario, it may make sense to take a performance hit once on write, to improve subsequent read performance.

If you anticipate "large" data volumes, I'd definitely go with the extra table to hold the high level totals. You need to ensure though that it is updated when a (monetary) transaction is made, within a (sql server) transaction to make it an atomic operation.

With smaller data volumes, you could get away without it...personally, I'd probably still go down that path, to simplify the read scenario.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense to go with the denormalized approach (the first solution) only if you face significant performance issues. Since you are doing just simple SUM (or group by and then sum) with proper indexes, your normalized solution will work really well and will be a lot easier to maintain (as you noted).

But depending on your queries, it can make sense to go with denormalized solution...for example, if your database is read/only (you periodically load data from some other data source and don't make inserts/updates at all or make them really rarely), then you can just load data in the easiest way to make queries...and in that case, denormalized solution might prove to be better.